# $f(1/n)=1/n$ implies $f(z)=z$

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

> If $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is entire and satisfies $f(1/n)=1/n$ then $f(z)=z$.

I am trying to prove this. What I have so far: by continuity $f(0)=0$. Since $f(1)=1$, it feels tempting to show that $|f(z)|\leq 1$ on the unit disk. Then, by Schwarz' lemma, we would get $f(z)=az$ on the disk, and hence $f(z)=z$ since $f$ entire. My question is:

Does the condition indeed imply $f(z)\leq 1$, and if so, why?

Comment: Do you know something called "the identity theorem"?

Comment: @StevenGubkin No I don't

Comment: Check your book.  I am sure that the identity theorem will have been established before Schwarz' lemma.  It immediately answers your question.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Thanks, it doesn't appear to (the statement and proof of Shwarz' lemma was given as an exercise), but having googled it this does seem like the way to go. I guess I will set about proving the theorem then. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so this does not go unanswered:

The identity theorem is the following:

> If $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic on a domain $\Omega$, and $f = g$ on some subset $S \subset \Omega$, and $S$ has a limit point in $\Omega$, then $f = g$ on all of $\Omega$

The proof can be found on wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem

The question in the OP is immediately answered by this theorem.

Comment: The accumulation point condition is interesting. I am guessing something like $f(n)=n$ doesn't imply $f$ is the identity then?

Comment: @user118224 Right.  For instance, $\sin(2\pi z)+z$ is a holomorphic function for which $f(n) = n$, but is not the identity.

Comment: The way I think of the identity theorem intuitively is like this:  A sequence If I know $z_n \to p$, and I know all of the function values $f(z_n)$, and I know $f$ is holomorphic, then this is enough information to compute $f(p)$ (as the limit of $f(z_n)$), $f'(p)$ (as the limit of $\frac{f(z_{n+1})-f(z_n)}{z_{n+1}-z_n}$), $f''(p)$ (as the limit of higher order difference quotients), ..., so I can find the Taylor series of $f$.  But once I have the Taylor series, by analyticity I have specified the function uniquely.